# Invertibility of the characteristic map

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

We are in the context of Hamilton Jacobi equations, in particular I was studying the characteristic method. We want to solve the problem of the special form (Hamiltonian only depending on the "$p$" variables) $$
\begin{cases}
u_t(x,t)+H\big(D_xu(x,t)\big)= 0, \\
u(x,0)=g,
\end{cases}\quad(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^+ .
$$ 
In this case it's easy to find that the characteristic line starting from $y$ at time $s$ is 
$$
X(y,s) = y+sDH\big(Dg(y)\big).
$$
Now set $$\overline{T} = \sup \Big\{ t : \, \det\big[I+tD^2H\big(Dg(y)\big)D^2g(y)\big] >0, \, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n \Big\}$$

The problem is that the textbook says that if $D^2H$ and $D^2g$ (Hessian matrices) are bounded, then for all $s < \overline{T}$  the function $y \mapsto X(y,s)$ is invertible (with $C^1$ inverse, but that's clear from the local inverse function theorem since the Jacobian is inverbile by hypothesis).

What I can't do is proving surjectivity and injectivity of this map. Can someone help me? Thanks!

P.S. The textbook i'm referring to is P.L. Lions, *Generalized solutions of Hamilton Jacobi equations*, page 14.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to show surjectivity and injectivity, it follows directly from the inverse function theorem.

First, a small missprint: $\overline{T}$ should be

$$\overline{T} = \sup \{ t : \, \det(I+tD^2H(Dg(y))D^2g(y)) >0 \, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$$

By the inverse function theorem, $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ has a local inverse when the determinant of the Jacobian is non-zero. The Jacobian of $y\mapsto y+sDH(Dg(y))$ is

$$I+sD^2H(Dg(y))D^2g(y)$$

and by definition, whenever $s<\overline{T}$ you have $\det(I+sD^2H(Dg(y))D^2g(y)) >0$ and therefore the map is invertible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Anyway, that is my problem: how do you recover global invertibility from just the local invertibility of the function?

Comment: @astrobarrel think for a moment how is defined $\overline{T}$: it is the supremum of the times $t$ for which the defining matrix is invertible ***for all*** $y\in\Bbb R^n$. Then, as MOMO shows, you have a local invertibility result which holds ***for all*** the space points $y$, provided $t\in[0,\overline{T}]$ and hence you have a ***global in space invertibility result***.

Comment: But the fact that the jacobian matrix is non singular everywhere does NOT imply in general that the function is globally invertible! there are a lot of counterexamples to this fact. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Think for example about the function $(x,y) \mapsto (e^x\cos(y),e^x\sin(y))$ Of course the Jacobian is always invertible so we have for each point a local invertibility result but the function is not injective (it's periodic!!)